# Printing all files' names from a folder (Kaggle kernel)

Tags: kaggle

```
train_dir= '../input/train'    
for file in os.listdir(train_dir):
    print(file)
```

I am trying to get all the file names in a directory called "train", from a Kaggle dataset.

However, using the above code I just get a return of the folder "train", instead of all the images in the folder "train".

If I repeat the code above using:

```
data_dir = '../input'    
for file in os.listdir(data_dir):
    print(file)
```

Then, it works correctly, it outputs the folder "train", the file "train.csv", the file "sample_submission.csv" and the folder "test" correctly.

Hence, I am quite puzzled why it doesn't work in the first case.

Thanks a lot. I am working directly on the Kaggle kernel by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a simple

```
import os
print(os.listdir("../input"))
```

works pretty well. Modify as required